# syntax for searching artifactory using command line

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to do a search on my instance of artifactory, using cml:

```
 JFROG="--url $URL --user $USER --password $PASSWORD"
 jfrog rt s $JFROG "some-local-repo/*log4j*"
```

But I keep getting:

```
 [Info] Searching artifacts...
 [Info] Found 0 artifacts.
```

Meanwhile if  I log in through web gui, i can get results back using similar search query... I tried searching for different libraries, to no avail. URL points to a vm running artifactory... Ex: http://somevm:20000/artifactory

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax:

```
JFROG="--url $URL --user $USER --password $PASSWORD"
jfrog rt s $JFROG <my local repo>/<name of artifact>/
```

That last forward slash is mucho importante